# IS my proof that $(A^c \cup(B-C))^C \subseteq C \cup (A-B)$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Suppose that $$(A^c \cup(B-C))^C$$ and let $x$ be an arbitrary element thereof. Thus by definition of complement of a set $$ x \notin A^c \land x \notin (B-C)$$ So $$x \in A \land \lnot (x \in B \land x \notin C ) $$ Which is equivalent to $$x \in A \land x \notin B \lor x \in C$$ Since $x$ was arbitrary. it follows that $$C \cup (A-B)$$Thus, $$(A^c \cup(B-C))^C \subseteq C \cup (A-B)$$

Comment: You have the line $x\in A\wedge x\notin B\vee x\in C$.  It is ambiguous whether you mean $(x\in A\wedge x\notin B)\vee x\in C$ or if you mean $x\in A\wedge (x\notin B\vee x\in C)$, both of which mean **different things**.  In general $(A\cap B)\cup C\neq A\cap (B\cup C)$.

Comment: I feel the formal logic symbols obscure your meaning. For example, "$x \notin A^c$ and $x \notin (B - C)$" is easier to read than the version with $\wedge$. I would probably go further and write "$x$ is neither an element of $A^c$ nor $B - C$", but this is all a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align*}
(A^c \cup (B-C))^c &= A \cap (B-C)^c\\
&= A \cap \left(B\cap C^c \right)^c\\
&=A \cap (B^c \cup C)\\
&= (A\cap C) \cup (A\cap B^c)\\
&=(A\cap C)\cup (A-B)\\
&\subseteq  C\cup (A-B).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Almost correct; you should have parentheses in
$$
x \in A \land (x \notin B \lor x \in C)
$$
which becomes
$$
(x\in A\land x\notin B)\lor(x\in A\land x\in C)
$$
from which it follows that $x\in A-B$ or $x\in A\cap C$ (in particular $x\in C)$.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Guess I shouldn't remove parentheses arbitrarily.